# Redraw DC JS Charts with New Data

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have data from a CSV in a crossfilter that looks like this:

hood,rooms,timestamp,price,occupancy

SF,2-Br,9/1/14,3950,.94

I load my data and then set up my Filters:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var all = ndx.groupAll();

var price = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.price;
}); 

var occupancy = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.occupancy
}) 

var roomType = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    var room = d.rooms_clean;
    return room; 
});  

var dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.day;
    });                       

var hood = ndx.dimension(function (d) {   //dimensions for choropleth
    return d.hood;
});

dataUnit = "price"
var roomAll = roomType.group().reduce(reduceAddAvg(dataUnit), reduceRemoveAvg(dataUnit), reduceInitAvg) // create vector with stats by room type 
var hoodAll = hood.group().reduce(reduceAddAvg(dataUnit), reduceRemoveAvg(dataUnit), reduceInitAvg) // create vector with stats by hood
var dateAll = dateDimension.group().reduce(reduceAddAvg(dataUnit), reduceRemoveAvg(dataUnit), reduceInitAvg) // create vector with stats by date
var roomGroup = roomType.group();
```

All of my charts are based on the dataUnit = "price".  I can reload the page setting dataUnit = "occupancy", and the charts render correctly.

I want to allow the user to click a button and for the new crossfilter to render in the page.  I've tried creating a button with Jquery to dispose of all the dimensions and create new ones:

```
   $('#occupancy').click(function() {

    roomType.dispose()
    hood.dispose()
    dateDimension.dispose()

    dataUnit = "occupancy"
    var roomAll = roomType.group().reduce(reduceAddAvg(dataUnit), reduceRemoveAvg(dataUnit), reduceInitAvg) // create vector with stats by room type 
    var hoodAll = hood.group().reduce(reduceAddAvg(dataUnit), reduceRemoveAvg(dataUnit), reduceInitAvg) // create vector with stats by hood
    var dateAll = dateDimension.group().reduce(reduceAddAvg(dataUnit), reduceRemoveAvg(dataUnit), reduceInitAvg) // create vector with stats by date
    var roomGroup = roomType.group();     

    dc.redrawAll();             
    return false;
})
```

but this just causes the map not to update.  How can I switch the dimension /data that all of the crossfilters use without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is leave the dimensions alone, but replace the groups each time a new calculation is selected.

Your quoted code is disposing but not recreating the dimensions; it is creating new groups but not disposing the old ones. It doesn't look like you want to recreate the dimensions, so those dispose calls are probably not a good idea.

You will need to assign the new groups to the charts. Just creating crossfilter objects does not let dc.js know about them (and using the same variables or variable names doesn't mean it will pick them up either).

Do `chart.group(...)` for each chart and its recreated group and you should see the update. You should probably dispose the old groups instead of the dimensions as well.